# probability of getting the right answer

Tags: probability, combinations

> Imagine we have 10 numbers.
> One of the team members mistakenly entered $2$ of the $6$ positive numbers as negative and $2$ of the $4$ negative numbers as positive.
> A player selects $3$ distinct numbers from $10$ given numbers and multiplies them. What's the probability of getting the right answer?

$2$ of $6$ positives numbers are wrong and $2$ of $4$ negative numbers are also wrong. The only way we can get the right answer is that we either choose all three numbers from the right ones or pick one number from the right ones and 2 numbers from the wrong ones.

$$\frac{C(4,2)C(6,2)C(4,2)C(6,1)+C(4,2)C(6,2)C(4,0)C(6,3)}{C(10,3)}= 144$$

Can someone explain whats the right way to solve this question?

Answer (score 1):

Let $E(n)$ be the event that there were $n$ mistakes
made in selecting at random 3 of the numbers out of 10.
Here, $n ~\in ~\{0, 1, 2, 3\}.$
Let $p[E(n)]$ denote the probability of event $E(n)$ occurring.

4 of the 10 numbers have the sign wrong.

You want $p[E(0)] + p[E(2)].$

$p[E(0)] = \frac{\binom{6}{3}}{\binom{10}{3}}.$

$p[E(2)] = \frac{\binom{6}{1} \times \binom{4}{2}}{\binom{10}{3}}.$

The idea behind computing $p[E(2)]$ is that you have to consider 
how many ways of selecting 1 # from the 6 good ones and 
2 #'s from the 4 bad ones.

The idea behind the commonly used denominator (i.e. sample space) 
of $\binom{10}{3}$ is that you are computing how many ways you can 
select 3 numbers out of 10.